# GAE: Unit testing DeadlineExceededError

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I've been using testbed, webtest, and nose to test my Python GAE app, and it is a great setup.  I'm now implementing something similar to [Nick's great example of using the deferred library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html), but I can't figure out a good way to test the parts of the code triggered by `DeadlineExceededError`.

Since this is in the context of a taskqueue, it would be painful to construct a test that took more than 10 minutes to run.  Is there a way to temporarily set the taskqueue time limit to a few seconds for the purpose of testing?  Or perhaps some other way to elegantly test the execution of code in the `except DeadlineExceededError` block?

Comment: Ultimately, all you need is something that will throw that exception when you want it to. Can't you just write a trivial method that throws it, and use a mock library to substitute it in where it's needed?

Comment: @Nick, I've never done a mock so I'm a bit lost here.  Are you suggesting that I mock my own code in the unit test, mock the GAE deferred library, or something else?  Any additional pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mock whatever method you want to throw that exception - probably one of the SDK functions.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract the "GAE context" for your code. in production provide real "GAE implementation" for testing provide a mock own that will raise the DeadlineExceededError. The test should not depend on any timeout, should be fast.

Sample abstraction (just glue):

```
class AbstractGAETaskContext(object):
  def task_spired(): pass # this will throw exception in mock impl

  # here you define any method that you call into GAE, to be mocked
  def defered(...): pass
```

If you don't like abstraction, you can do monkey patching for testing only, also you need to define the task_expired function to be your hook for testing.
task_expired should be called during your task implementation function.

**UPDATED**This the 3rd solution:

First I want to mention that the [Nick's sample implementation](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) is not so great, the Mapper class has to many responsabilities(deferring, query data, update in batch); and this make the test hard to made, a lot of mocks need to be defined. So I extract the deferring responsabilities in a separate class. *You only want to test that deferring mechanism, what actually is happen(the update, query, etc) should be handled in other test*.

Here is deffering class, also this no more depends on GAE:

```
class DeferredCall(object):
  def __init__(self, deferred):
    self.deferred = deferred

  def run(self, long_execution_call, context, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' long_execution_call should return a tuple that tell us how was terminate operation, with timeout and the context where was abandoned '''
    next_context, timeouted = long_execution_call(context, *args, **kwargs)
    if timeouted:
        self.deferred(self.run, next_context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the test module:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_defer(self):
        calls = []
        def mock_deferrer(callback, *args, **kwargs):
            calls.append((callback, args, kwargs))

        def interrupted(self, context):
            return "new_context", True

        d = DeferredCall()
        d.run(interrupted, "init_context")
        self.assertEquals(1, len(calls), 'a deferred call should be')


    def test_no_defer(self):
        calls = []
        def mock_deferrer(callback, *args, **kwargs):
            calls.append((callback, args, kwargs))

        def completed(self, context):
            return None, False

        d = DeferredCall()
        d.run(completed, "init_context")
        self.assertEquals(0, len(calls), 'no deferred call should be')
```

How will look the Nick's Mapper implementation:

```
class Mapper:
    ...
    def _continue(self, start_key, batch_size):
        ... # here is same code, nothing was changed
        except DeadlineExceededError:
            # Write any unfinished updates to the datastore.
            self._batch_write()
            # Queue a new task to pick up where we left off.
            ##deferred.defer(self._continue, start_key, batch_size)
            return start_key, True ## make compatible with DeferredCall
            self.finish()
            return None, False ## make it comaptible with DeferredCall

    runner = _continue
```

Code where you register the long running task; this only depend on the GAE deferred lib.

```
import DeferredCall
import PersonMapper # this inherits the Mapper
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

mapper = PersonMapper()
DeferredCall(deferred).run(mapper.run)
```

Comment: Since I'm testing with testbed and webtest, I think monkey patching would be the better approach.  Do you know how to do the necessary monkey patching for this?

Comment: @Jeff: No, the monkey patching is the last solution to use it in general, especially in unit-testing. As a general guide if you cannot test something easy that refactore it! So 3rd approach came out.